# how to press the key automatically in the game?

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, keypress

sorry in advance for my bad english.
I'm writing a game automation program , specifically the game requires a key press to start doing (something) , but when i use KeyBoard.press() function from KeyBoard module i have problem where game doesn't recognize my key i tried in game chat box and it still works , it means the key is still pressed down but the game doesn't pick up , i tried using some other functions like " KeyBoard.press_and_release() , KeyBoard.send() " and some other modules but the result is the same,

here is the example code

```
While True:
    if (...):
        keyboard.press('e')
        keyboard.release('e')
```

but what confuses me is when i add time.sleep() between the press and release commands it works but what confuses me is when i add time.sleep() between the press and release commands it works but there is a big delay
Anyone have any solution for me?

```
While True:
    if (...):
        keyboard.press('e')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        keyboard.release('e')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly (and, I might not, sorry) it could be an issue with the game rather than python. Some games, especially online games, implement features specifically to stop automation.

Have you tried your code in a different context - another game or, seeing as it simulates key presses, a text editor? I think you are saying it works in the chat box but not for game control inputs. If it works as intended outside of the game but not inside that would suggest the problem is something to do with how the game handles key presses.

In that while loop, you might be simulating 20 key presses a second, while a more usual average would be between about 5 and 7 with the world record reported at 16. Perhaps the game detects if the rate is too high and discounts those key presses. Also, a physical keyboard will be subject to repeat rate and repeat delay, which the game may be testing to specifically try and eliminate this type of virtualized automation. Or, something else entirely - without knowing which game you are trying to automate I am left with guess work.

That said, with your reference to an in-game chat box, I strongly suspect you are trying to automate an online multi-player game. Even if you are just doing it for your own personal interest (and not to get an advantage over other players), that kind of thing is frowned upon and can potentially get your game account banned. I would normally suggest you share which game you are trying to automate with the community to get more specific information, but I doubt you will be happy to do that.